# (iphone) make singleton of custom activity indicator?

Tags: iphone, singleton, activity-indicator

I'm trying to add my custom activity indicator to my app.

Since there are many places I want to show the indicator,
I thought maybe it's a good idea to make it singleton to access it easily.

I guess I can slightly modify this to make the desired singleton class.
[Singleton Class iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083025/singleton-class-iphone)

One problem is that I need to add the indicator view to some view(as subview) obviously.
And wonder if there is a singleton -like view that I can access from anywhere to add the indicator view as subview.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use singleton, but I would advise you not to use singleton for UIView elements.

UIView elements can only have one superview, so if you use singleton.activityindicator everywhere, you will have to remove it from superview before adding it to new view, so alot of bookkeeping is required.  For example, you have to remove it from prev superview when showing it else where, and when you come back to prev superview (through user clicking on some nav control or something), you have to determine if you need to now add it back to the new superview, etc.

I do use singleton for one UIView in my design, that is Ad banner view.  I wanted to keep one ad across the app, to have same ad in different nav controllers.  However it was big pain in the butt.

Just create one, add to the view, and remove when done.. simpler in my opinion :)

Comment: I thought, adding to a view as subview automatically removes it from previous superview. correct me if i'm wrong please

Comment: Let me know if it is.  from my testing, it didn't autoremove from superview.  When I add my singleton adview to many superviews, none of the superview can display it (it is all blacked out). also, what about cases where activity indicator is coming and going?  For example, let's say you start activity, so it shows in current view.  During the activity, you push a new view - then activity finishes, then you pop back.  How are you going to handle whether you should readd activity into it?  Much easier to keep activity indicator per viewcontrlr, and let delegate methods for each handle show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a `UIView` to the custom class and then add the `activityIndicator` to it.

Answer (score -1):

Take a `UIView` Class

inside `initWithFrame` methode:

```
 //this method create custom activity indicator
     UIImage *startImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
     customActivityIndicator = [[UIImageView alloc] //take in in .h file
            initWithImage:startImage ];


   //Add more images which to be used for the animation
   customActivityIndicator.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
           nil];


  //Set animation duration 
  customActivityIndicator.animationDuration = 0.5;


  //set frame at the middle of the imageview 
  customActivityIndicator.frame = self.frame;
```

Take a methode:

```
// call this methode from the class where u want to animate custom indicator
(void)startAnimating
{
    [customActivityIndicatorstartAnimating];
}
```

Take a methode:

```
// call this methode from the class where u want to stope animate custom 
(void)stopAnimating 
{
    [customActivityIndicatorstaopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: This is not a singleton at all ; )